# how to use an extension method from a code block in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, extension-methods

I have an extension method which I can use from the .cs codebehind of an aspx page, but if I try to do it in a code block in the aspx, it can't find the extension method.  Is there something I need to add to the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the namespace containing the extension method at the top of the page, like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Your.Namespace" %>
```

You can also include it globally in Web.config:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Your.Namespace" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize I'd have to do that, because the extension method is in the same namespace as the code behind class.

Comment: if the extension is in another assembly you also need <add assembly in the web.config

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate using directive:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="NamespaceContainingTheStaticClass" %>
```

Or even better do it globally in [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx)

```
<pages>
   <namespaces>
      <add namespace="NamespaceContainingTheStaticClass" />
   </namespaces>
</pages>
```